# How do I mix boolean comparisons and 'if let' statements in a clean way?

Tags: syntax, rust

I am writing a function which depends on comparing booleans, and also checking an enum's type using the 'if let' syntax. Is there a cleaner way than what I have below?

```
fn is_mine(&self, row: i32, col: i32) -> bool {
    if self.bounds.is_in_bounds(row, col) {
        if let MineCell::Mine = self.field[row as usize][col as usize] {
            return true;
        }
    }

    false
}
```

This works, but it feels dirty by returning true/false as the only statement inside of an 'if' block. In my case, the boolean comparison in the `.is_in_bounds()` member has to occur first, then the `if let` check on the enum's type is safe to do.

This is technically correct, but I feel like there has to be a more idiomatic way to do this. I've seen posts here and elsewhere about how to properly stack `if let` statements, but nothing about mixing boolean comparisons and `if let` comparisons.

Should I accept the correct but ugly form of the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your enum implements `PartialEq`, this should also work:

```rust
fn is_mine(&self, row: i32, col: i32) -> bool {
    self.bounds.is_in_bounds(row, col)
        && self.field[row as usize][col as usize] == MineCell::Mine
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a single expression using [`std::mem::discriminant`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.discriminant.html) like this:

```
fn is_mine(&self, row: i32, col: i32) -> bool {
    use std::mem::discriminant;

    self.bounds.is_in_bounds(row, col)
        && discriminant(&self.field[row as usize][col as usize])
            == discriminant(&MineCell::Mine)
}
```

Remember that in Rust, logical operators short-circuit, so the part after the `&&` will only be executed if the first part is true.